# When can I recycle my Macbook Air (mid-2013)?

Tags: macbook-pro

I was interested in recycling my Macbook Air Intel Core i7 1.7 GHz 13" (mid-2013), however, when I went to get started on the recycling program, this model was not listed. I was just wondering when it would be available to be recycled or if I was doing something wrong or missed something.

Answer (score 2):

The [Frequently asked questions about the Apple Reuse and Recycling Program](https://www.apple.com/recycling/gift-card/faq.html) page says (emphasis mine):

> Which products qualify for the Apple Recycling Program?
>
> Any Mac or PC desktop or notebook computer ***may*** qualify for reuse. Any Apple-branded product can be recycled for free.

We can infer that it's at Apple's discretion to provide *free* recycling for specific Apple hardware (or non Apple hardware). There is no fixed time line for product ranges to be eligible for recycling through Apple.

Since the MacBook Air Mid 2013 is not listed in the list of MacBook Air models that can be recycled through Apple (the latest at this point being the Mid 2012 model), your choices now are to ***sell it to someone else*** (since it's a recent machine and has a lot of value left) or [recycle it for free](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/reuse_and_recycle) through *Sims Recycling Solutions* (which means you get nothing for the Mac, as opposed to the standard process where Apple evaluates the value of the Mac and sends you a gift card if it has any value).

> **Recycle it for free.**
> You can still recycle it by calling Sims Recycling Solutions at 800-966-4135
> for a free shipping label and packaging instructions.